# gstreamer multichannel greater than 8 channels

Tags: audio, gstreamer

Good afternoon, Up until now I have been using gstreamer to stream 8 channel audio with no issues.
I generate 8 mono channels in audacity and export a wav file.

I was recently asked to support 16 channels and was surprised to find that 16 channels (or anything above 8) is not supported. The command line gstreamer command to stream a wav file used can be seen below:

```
GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=~/Desktop/8ch_16_test_diagwav.wav ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw,format=S16BE,rate=48000,channels=16 ! filesink location=/tmp/filesink0
```

I get the following error when this is run with the 16 channel file:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
0:00:00.041995106  3534 0x55b0024a4e10 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3583:gst_base_src_start_complete:<filesrc0> pad not activated yet
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
0:00:00.046842761  3534 0x7f833806ec00 FIXME                default gstutils.c:3981:gst_pad_create_stream_id_internal:<wavparse0:src> Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
0:00:00.091236225  3534 0x7f833806ec00 WARN         audio-resampler audio-resampler.c:274:convert_taps_gint16_c: can't find exact taps
0:00:00.091319797  3534 0x7f833806ec00 WARN            audioconvert gstaudioconvert.c:654:gst_audio_convert_fixate_channels:<audioconvert1> invalid or unexpected channel-positions
0:00:00.091329274  3534 0x7f833806ec00 ERROR           audioconvert gstaudioconvert.c:668:gst_audio_convert_fixate_channels:<audioconvert1> Have no default layout for 16 channels
0:00:00.091339971  3534 0x7f833806ec00 ERROR             audio-info audio-info.c:304:gst_audio_info_from_caps: no channel-mask property given
0:00:00.091344101  3534 0x7f833806ec00 ERROR           audioconvert gstaudioconvert.c:778:gst_audio_convert_set_caps:<audioconvert1> invalid output caps
0:00:00.091356433  3534 0x7f833806ec00 WARN           basetransform gstbasetransform.c:1362:gst_base_transform_setcaps:<audioconvert1> FAILED to configure incaps audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, channels=(int)8, channel-mask=(bitmask)0x0000000000000c3f, rate=(int)48000 and outcaps audio/x-raw, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, format=(string)S16BE, channels=(int)16
0:00:00.091398546  3534 0x7f833806ec00 WARN            audioconvert gstaudioconvert.c:654:gst_audio_convert_fixate_channels:<audioconvert1> invalid or unexpected channel-positions
0:00:00.091404430  3534 0x7f833806ec00 ERROR           audioconvert gstaudioconvert.c:668:gst_audio_convert_fixate_channels:<audioconvert1> Have no default layout for 16 channels
0:00:00.091411526  3534 0x7f833806ec00 ERROR             audio-info audio-info.c:304:gst_audio_info_from_caps: no channel-mask property given
0:00:00.091415084  3534 0x7f833806ec00 ERROR           audioconvert gstaudioconvert.c:778:gst_audio_convert_set_caps:<audioconvert1> invalid output caps
0:00:00.091423006  3534 0x7f833806ec00 WARN           basetransform gstbasetransform.c:1362:gst_base_transform_setcaps:<audioconvert1> FAILED to configure incaps audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, channels=(int)8, channel-mask=(bitmask)0x0000000000000c3f, rate=(int)48000 and outcaps audio/x-raw, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, format=(string)S16BE, channels=(int)16
0:00:00.091461862  3534 0x7f833806ec00 WARN            audioconvert gstaudioconvert.c:654:gst_audio_convert_fixate_channels:<audioconvert1> invalid or unexpected channel-positions
0:00:00.091467389  3534 0x7f833806ec00 ERROR           audioconvert gstaudioconvert.c:668:gst_audio_convert_fixate_channels:<audioconvert1> Have no default layout for 16 channels
0:00:00.091473940  3534 0x7f833806ec00 ERROR             audio-info audio-info.c:304:gst_audio_info_from_caps: no channel-mask property given
0:00:00.091477330  3534 0x7f833806ec00 ERROR           audioconvert gstaudioconvert.c:778:gst_audio_convert_set_caps:<audioconvert1> invalid output caps
0:00:00.091484711  3534 0x7f833806ec00 WARN           basetransform gstbasetransform.c:1362:gst_base_transform_setcaps:<audioconvert1> FAILED to configure incaps audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, channels=(int)8, channel-mask=(bitmask)0x0000000000000c3f, rate=(int)48000 and outcaps audio/x-raw, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, format=(string)S16BE, channels=(int)16
0:00:00.091521324  3534 0x7f833806ec00 WARN            audioconvert gstaudioconvert.c:654:gst_audio_convert_fixate_channels:<audioconvert1> invalid or unexpected channel-positions
0:00:00.091526722  3534 0x7f833806ec00 ERROR           audioconvert gstaudioconvert.c:668:gst_audio_convert_fixate_channels:<audioconvert1> Have no default layout for 16 channels
0:00:00.091533191  3534 0x7f833806ec00 ERROR             audio-info audio-info.c:304:gst_audio_info_from_caps: no channel-mask property given
0:00:00.091536562  3534 0x7f833806ec00 ERROR           audioconvert gstaudioconvert.c:778:gst_audio_convert_set_caps:<audioconvert1> invalid output caps
0:00:00.091543448  3534 0x7f833806ec00 WARN           basetransform gstbasetransform.c:1362:gst_base_transform_setcaps:<audioconvert1> FAILED to configure incaps audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, channels=(int)8, channel-mask=(bitmask)0x0000000000000c3f, rate=(int)48000 and outcaps audio/x-raw, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, format=(string)S16BE, channels=(int)16
0:00:00.091554349  3534 0x7f833806ec00 WARN                wavparse gstwavparse.c:2293:gst_wavparse_loop:<wavparse0> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:00.091558663  3534 0x7f833806ec00 WARN                wavparse gstwavparse.c:2293:gst_wavparse_loop:<wavparse0> error: streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstWavParse:wavparse0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstwavparse.c(2293): gst_wavparse_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstWavParse:wavparse0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
0:00:00.091614021  3534 0x7f833806ec00 WARN            audioconvert gstaudioconvert.c:654:gst_audio_convert_fixate_channels:<audioconvert1> invalid or unexpected channel-positions
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
0:00:00.091619464  3534 0x7f833806ec00 ERROR           audioconvert gstaudioconvert.c:668:gst_audio_convert_fixate_channels:<audioconvert1> Have no default layout for 16 channels
0:00:00.091662384  3534 0x7f833806ec00 ERROR             audio-info audio-info.c:304:gst_audio_info_from_caps: no channel-mask property given
0:00:00.091681343  3534 0x7f833806ec00 ERROR           audioconvert gstaudioconvert.c:778:gst_audio_convert_set_caps:<audioconvert1> invalid output caps
0:00:00.091701845  3534 0x7f833806ec00 WARN           basetransform gstbasetransform.c:1362:gst_base_transform_setcaps:<audioconvert1> FAILED to configure incaps audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, channels=(int)8, channel-mask=(bitmask)0x0000000000000c3f, rate=(int)48000 and outcaps audio/x-raw, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, format=(string)S16BE, channels=(int)16
0:00:00.091767321  3534 0x7f833806ec00 WARN            audioconvert gstaudioconvert.c:654:gst_audio_convert_fixate_channels:<audioconvert1> invalid or unexpected channel-positions
0:00:00.091773142  3534 0x7f833806ec00 ERROR           audioconvert gstaudioconvert.c:668:gst_audio_convert_fixate_channels:<audioconvert1> Have no default layout for 16 channels
0:00:00.091779617  3534 0x7f833806ec00 ERROR             audio-info audio-info.c:304:gst_audio_info_from_caps: no channel-mask property given
0:00:00.091797568  3534 0x7f833806ec00 ERROR           audioconvert gstaudioconvert.c:778:gst_audio_convert_set_caps:<audioconvert1> invalid output caps
0:00:00.091805352  3534 0x7f833806ec00 WARN           basetransform gstbasetransform.c:1362:gst_base_transform_setcaps:<audioconvert1> FAILED to configure incaps audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, channels=(int)8, channel-mask=(bitmask)0x0000000000000c3f, rate=(int)48000 and outcaps audio/x-raw, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, format=(string)S16BE, channels=(int)16
Freeing pipeline ...
```

When using an 8channel file and channel =8 with a wav file generated from the same audacity project, everything is fine.

For now testing with

```
linux
gst-launch-1.0 version 1.14.4
GStreamer 1.14.4
```

Is it not at all possible to stream a 16ch wav file with gstreamer from commandline? I have tried looking at the various flags such as interleave, channel-positions etc but do not have enough experience to know offhand what may be needed.

any help or links would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 1):

After quite a bit of searching and experimenting I finally found a working solution.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=16ch_16bit_10s.wav ! decodebin ! capssetter caps="audio/x-raw,channels=16,rate=48000,channel-mask=(bitmask)0xffff" ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! "audio/x-raw,rate=48000,format=S16BE" ! queue ! capssetter caps="audio/x-raw,channels=16,rate=48000,channel-mask=(bitmask)0xffff" ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! filesink location=audiosink
```

Where bitmask value =  (2^channels) - 1 in a hex string format.

This was mainly found through trail and error using the following as reference:
[interleaving 4 channels of audio into vorbisenc or opusenc in gstreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287949/interleaving-4-channels-of-audio-into-vorbisenc-or-opusenc-in-gstreamer)

Unfortunately I don't have enough experience (or smart enough) to fully understand why this works.  What capsetter actually does and why an `"audio/x-raw,rate=48000,format=S16BE"` is needed between the upstream and downstream is anyone's guess. Might be nice if someone could edit/comment a better explanation?

with this solution I can switch between 16-24 bit and 1,2,4,8,16 channel.

Comment: you mean "trial and error"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps on the Audacity side something went wrong?

The following creates a 16 channel .wav file for me:

```
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc is-live=true ! \
  audio/x-raw,format=S16BE,rate=48000,channels=16 ! \
  audioresample ! audioconvert ! wavenc ! filesink location=x.wav
```

ffprobe:

```
Input #0, wav, from 'x.wav':
  Duration: 00:23:18.06, bitrate: 24 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 16 channels, s16, 12288 kb/s
```

The file also plays fine with `gst-play-1.0 x.wav`. This is all on GStreamer 1.16.2.

Comment: Hi thanks, I am unsure if this is the same thing though? I am not trying to generate a 16 channel wav. I have a 16 channel wav and gstreamer is supposed to read that wav file and write raw audio to file. I tried the command you posted above which was fine. But then if you try something like: gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=x.wav ! \
  audio/x-raw,format=S16BE,rate=48000,channels=16 ! \
  audioresample ! audioconvert ! wavenc ! filesink location=y.wav  you end up with similar issues.

Comment: You can't just dictate caps there. What is its purpose at that position? `gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=x.wav ! wavparse ! filesink location=x.raw` works just fine and writes raw PCM without WAV header.

Comment: Sorry, I am definitely not a pro when it comes to gstreamer. Wondering if there is way to specify bit depth and/or channel count in the raw audio. I tried the above and don't get errors but the audio is corrupted/not the right format. From the original question I assume this has something to do with either decodebin, audioconvert ,audioresample or audio/x-raw? Unfortunately I did not set this up and was just asked to update so my knowledge is limited :(

Comment: The biggest question is what are you try to accomplish. Then again some operations have limitations. E.g. the `wavenc` does not support S16BE. I can't say out of my head if it's a `wavenc` limitation or by the wav format itself.

Comment: Hi @Florian Zwoch, sorry, yeah I realize I couldn't really provide the full detail. I did find a solution that I posted below. I appreciate the help though.